# DVR which does not contain $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, valuation-theory

I'm looking for a DVR which does not contain $\mathbb{Z}$ as a set.

N.B Here, I assume character of DVR is zero. In character $0$ , there are easy counter examples.

All DVR I know seems to contain $\mathbb{Z}$, and valuation on it, I saw notation
like $v(n)$, where $n$ is integer.

With a tacit understanding, it seems domain field of $v$ contains $\mathbb{Z}$.

Where am I missing?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is D in DVR ( ? valuation ring) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie [Discrete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_valuation_ring), I think.

Comment: DVR is discrete valuation ring here, defined as valuation ring which has value group which is isomorphic to Z as ordered group.

Comment: If by "as a set" you mean "as a subring", then $\mathbb F_p [\![ x ]\!]$ (power series over field with $p$ elements) is an example which doesn't contain $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, but that was not I was looking for. I assumed character is 0.

Comment: Any ring of characteristic zero will always has a subring isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: oh my god, I was lacking most important thing. Sorry to bother you. I should reflect on myself. Thank you so much.